# how to check if a word contains all letters in a string bash

Tags: string, bash

let's say I have a file containing words (one per line), and I have a string containing letters

```
str = "aeiou"
```

I want to check how many words in the file contain all the letters in string. They don't have to appear in order.
the first thing that came to mind was using cat and grep

```
cat wordfile | grep a | grep e | grep i | grep letters....
```

this seems to work, but I wonder if there's a better way.

Answer (score 2):

If the search string is fixed, you might try something like that:

```
cat wordfile | awk '/a/&&/e/&&/i/&&/o/&&/u/' | wc -l
```

---

If needed, the search pattern may easily been build using your favorite script language. As I favor Python:

```
str="aeiou"
search=$(python -c 'print "/"+"/&&/".join([c for c in "'"$str"'"])+"/"')
cat wordfile | awk "$search" | wc -l
```

Comment: the awk solution is probably the "smallest" solution. Good luck to all!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that is done solely in bash. Note the [[ ]] makes this non-portable to sh. This script will read every line in file and then test that it contains every character in `str`. The file to read must be the first argument for the script. The comments below describe the operation:

```
#!/bin/bash

str=aeiou

while read line || test -n "$line"; do    # read every line in file
    match=0;                              # initialize match = true
    for ((i=0; i<${#str}; i++)); do       # for each letter in string
        [[ $line =~ ${str:$i:1} ]] || {   # test it is contained in line - or
            match=1                       # set match false and
            break                         # break - goto next word
        }
    done 
    # if match still true, then all letters in string found in line
    test "$match" -eq 0 && echo "all found in '$line'"; 
done < "$1"

exit 0
```

testfile (dat/vowels.txt):

```
a_even_ice_dough_ball
a_even_ice_ball
someword
notallvowels
```

output:

```
$ bash vowel.sh dat/vowels.txt
all found in 'a_even_ice_dough_ball'
```

Answer (score 0):

Messy, but can be done in one step by turning on the PCRE-regex flag of GNU `grep`

```
 grep -P '^(?=.*a.*)(?=.*e.*)(?=.*i.*)(?=.*o.*)(?=.*u.*)' file | wc -l
```